# macOS Catalina USB keyboard doesn't work after being taken out and in again

Tags: keyboard, usb, catalina

After I upgraded to macOS Catalina on my MacBook Pro from 2013, my USB keyboard stops working every time I unplug it and plug it in again. Every time, I have to reboot with the keyboard plugged in to make it work again.

Is anybody else experiencing this issue and has a way to fix it because it is super annoying.

**Info about my mac:** MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

Test after this.

If this doesn't help then at last try to:

**Reset the SMC on Mac**

First, shut down your Mac and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Release all keys. And, Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

**Start up in safe mode**

Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. The Apple logo appears on your display.

Release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window. If your startup disk is encrypted with FileVault, you might be asked to log in twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the Finder.

To leave safe mode, restart your Mac without pressing any keys during startup.

This will release some kernel panic that might help to fix your issue too.

Comment: The second of your solutions worked for me, but the first on didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Wait...it only works the first time i unplug it and replug it, but if I do it more than once, it's the same bug. :-(

Comment: @BossElijah: Try to boot the machine in Safe boot mode and see if you still get this issue or not.

Comment: What is safe boot exactly?

Comment: @BossElijah: check and go through it https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: Thanks, if you add this link to your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @BossElijah: I updated my answer. So it would appreciate if you could accept it.

Comment: Sure! Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Apple keeps annoying its users with its ridiculous inventions. Got a brand new 3000eur Macbook Pro from work with Catalina. Mouse not working! They sell 75eur for a brittle intermediary piece for HDMI / 1 USB port that makes your screen flicker after some usage. It needs to stop!

Comment: Resetting PRAM worked for me. Doing it sent me afterward to Recovery Assistant, which I didn't expect. So from there I did Apple menu > restart. My (brand new) MBP running Big Sur now detects my Apple wired keyboard again.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixe my same issue. My issue would occur when my USB keyboard would stop working on my laptop after unplugging it and replugging it in while my computer was on. I would then have to reboot my computer all over again for it to work.

Restart or Start your computer in safe mode and then once you logged in try doing all the things with you keyboard that caused it not to work for yourself and if the issue goes away simply restart the computer without holding any keys and then the problem "should" go away. It worked for me and I am now able to unplug my keyboard and plug it back in and it works without having to restart everything.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: It is already fixed so I can't check if it works, but it looks fine.